# Pairwise regressions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regression

1. I have a Dataframe `df` with `n` columns. The index is a DatetimeIndex. Given a reference column `ref_col`, I wish to compute  the `n-1` one-dimensional linear regressions of the remaining columns against this reference column. The following does not achieve this, but rather computes a single `n-1`-dimensional regression:

   ```
   pd.ols(y=df[ref_col], x=df.drop(ref_col, axis=1))
   ```
2. Suppose now I wish to compute all possible pairwise regressions in order to produce an `nxn` matrix of betas with unit diagonal.

One can do both of the above relatively easily using loops. Is there a "vectorised" way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the list of the pairwise regressions to the reference column like this:

```
models=[pd.ols(y=df[ref_col],x=df[col]) for col in df if col<>ref_col]
```

To get the matrix of models over all possible reference columns, the next step would be

```
models_matrix=[[pd.ols(y=df[ref_col],x=df[col]) for col in df if col<>ref_col] for ref_col in df]
```

Finally, the matrix of betas can be achieved like this

```
betas=[[pd.ols(y=df[ref_col],x=df[col]).beta.x for col in df if col<>ref_col] for ref_col in df]
```

Answer (score 0):

Understand this was asked 8 years ago and the answer was resolved, still want to contribute the **vectorized solution** as I can't find it searching the website.

Based on my rough comparison, doing 1000 columns * 250 rows (499,500 combinations) in vectorized manner makes the entire process at least 10X faster.

below is the code:

```
def estimate_coef(x, y):
    # vectorized OLS to return alpha, beta, r^2 and other metrics I need to output

    # number of observations/points
    no_sample, no_col = x.shape
    
    # mean of x and y vector
    m_x = np.mean(x, axis=0)
    m_y = np.mean(y, axis=0)

    # calculating cross-deviation and deviation about x
    SS_xy = np.sum(y * x, axis=0) - no_sample * m_y * m_x
    SS_xx = np.sum(x * x, axis=0) - no_sample * m_x * m_x

    # calculating regression coefficients
    b_1 = SS_xy / SS_xx
    b_0 = m_y - b_1 * m_x
    y_hat = x * b_1.T + b_0
    resid = y - y_hat

    r_2 = 1 - np.power(resid, 2).sum(axis=0) / np.power(y - m_y, 2).sum(axis=0)
    arr_z = (resid - resid.mean(axis=0)) / resid.std(axis=0)
    params = np.array([b_0, b_1, r_2, resid[-1], arr_z[-1]])
    index = ["intercept", "slope", "r^2", "resid", "sigma"]

    return pd.DataFrame(params, index=index)


###
# generating dummy data
arr_x = []
arr_y = []
n = 250
sec = 501
for i in range(1, sec):
    x, y = make_regression(n_features=1, n_samples=n, noise=10)
    arr_x.append(x.reshape(-1))
    arr_y.append(y)
arr_x = np.array(arr_x).T
arr_y = np.array(arr_y).T
arr_xy = np.hstack([arr_x, arr_y])
df_xy = pd.DataFrame(arr_xy)
###
# the actual process
t1_start = time.perf_counter()
col = df_xy.columns
lst_tpl_comb = list(itertools.combinations(col, 2))
t1_stop_0 = time.perf_counter()
print("Elapsed time during the iteration:", t1_stop_0 - t1_start)
lst_arr_i = []
lst_arr_j = []
for i, j in lst_tpl_comb:
    lst_arr_i.append(arr_xy[:, i])
    lst_arr_j.append(arr_xy[:, j])
t1_stop_1 = time.perf_counter()
print("Elapsed time during the array looping:", t1_stop_1 - t1_stop_0)
x = np.array(lst_arr_i).T
y = np.array(lst_arr_j).T
t1_temp = time.perf_counter()
print("Elapsed time during the array stacking:", t1_temp - t1_stop_1)
df_param = estimate_coef(x, y)
df_param.columns = lst_tpl_comb
df_param = df_param.T
df_param.sort_values("r^2", inplace=True, ascending=False)
t1_stop_2 = time.perf_counter()
print("Elapsed time took during the regression:", t1_stop_2 - t1_temp)
print("total time took:", t1_stop_2 - t1_start)
```